# Outlook auto-complete not resolving properly

Tags: microsoft-outlook, autocomplete

Using Outlook 365 on Exchange server, auto-complete recently started behaving erratically. Many times, when I select a suggestion after typing a name, either by clicking or hitting enter, it does not resolve to a proper email address, resulting in namechecking being summonned at send time and usually being unable to resolve the name inserted.

To reiterate, I start typing in a field, get suggestions normally, select the suggestion normally however I please, but when it inserts my selection into the field, graphically it does not underline it like it normally should, indicating the address is not properly resolved, despite all the info being shown correctly (including display name and email address). Again, it writes "Display name '<email@address.com'>" (save the single quotes), but with no underlining as there should be. Hence, since the address is not resolved properly, name checking kicks in at send time nonetheless, and inevitably fails with no suggestion(s) shown whatsoever. To get my emails sending, after autocompletion finishes doing its trick, I have to manually delete all but the email address, which is annoying to say the least.

Please note I do not use English locale, which makes me wondering whether it could be a syntax issue somewhere, like it often is (commas vs semicolons; single and double quotes; etc.).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not really quite sure if this would be related to the syntax issue as you mentioned, I tested in my Outlook and those auto-complete entries will only show "Display name email@address.com" without both single and double quotes. Does this issue only happen to some specific contacts? Or randomly happen to different contacts?   Maybe you could try to remove those problematic entries and re-add them to see if the issue would still continues.